# ublox SARA-U201 cellular modem suddenly throwing errors on ATDT command

Tags: at-command, cellular-network, wwan

I have an Omega2 with the Hologram.io shield (which has a ublox SARA-U201 chip on it).  It was working fine when I noticed yesterday it wasn't online anymore. With some digging, I found that the chat script was failing because suddenly the  ATDT*99***1# is returning ERROR when it was called in the chat script. I've tried issuing an ATZ and an AT&F0, tried using AT&D0 in case it was RTS related.

The chat script is rather basic, just doing an AT check for OK before dialing. And was working for the past two years (although I only use the omega2 seldomly).  I have no clue what may have suddenly changed. Checking the hologram website, it doesn't appear that there's any problem with my account or a data balance or anything.

Any suggestions on what changed and/or how to fix it?

Comment: I assume that the PPPD doesn't restart working after an HW reboot, does it? After this assumption, there's something missing in your description. Chatscript usually contains also APN settings. Something like `AT+CGDCONT=1,IP,<APN_Name>`. Does your chatscript contain it? Could it be changed for your SIM operator? Are you able to try if connection works manually providing commands through serial interface?

Comment: Oh, I forgot this was still out here. I think it may have actually been a problem with the account balance that didn't reflect in their interface until days later. I ordered a different type of the same modem for raspberry pi and since I hadn't seen comments on here, I hadn't tried anything more with the omega2. But now that the other modem showed up yesterday, I was going to try playing with it again this evening after adding money to both sims

Comment: Oh, ok. A plane (the modem) running out of fuel (money) is a good reason for physics (SIM operator) make the plane crash (PPP stop). Joking aside, when something that used to work stops working is usually a crash of the modem; and if the problem persists after the modem reboot it is usually something related to the SIM operator (my question aimed in that direction).

Comment: You could enable verbose error responses with `AT+CMEE=2`.